# ASP.NET - cannot style forms

Tags: html, css, asp.net, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem applying CSS to `<form>` element and all nested elements inside. I do it by class .header_navbar_form and .header_navbar_form_input in stylesheet header.css, but only bootstrap takes effect. For some reason, other elements, such as `<div>`, `<p>`, `<h1>` are affected by the same stylesheet
Once again: div with id `header_navbar_div` is affected by the same stylesheet

cshtml:

```html
<div id="header_navbar_div">

    <form class="header_navbar_form" action="/Home/Index">
        <input class="header_navbar_form_input" type="submit" value="Uvod">
    </form>
    <form class="header_navbar_form" action="/Home/Locations">
        <input class="header_navbar_form_input" type="submit" value="Lokality">
    </form>
     <form class="header_navbar_form" action="/Home/Trips"> 
         <input class="header_navbar_form_input" type="submit" value="Nase vandry">
    </form>
    <form class="header_navbar_form" action="/Home/Equipment">  
        <input class="header_navbar_form_input" type="submit" value="Vybava">
    </form>
    <form class="header_navbar_form" action="/Home/Recipes">  
        <input class="header_navbar_form_input" type="submit" value="Kucharka">
    </form>
    <form class="header_navbar_form" action="/Home/Tips">  
        <input class="header_navbar_form_input" type="submit" value="Navody a rady">
    </form>
    <form class="header_navbar_form" action="/Home/Nature">  
        <input class="header_navbar_form_input" type="submit" value="O Prirode">
    </form>
    <form class="header_navbar_form" action="/Home/Songbook">  
        <input class="header_navbar_form_input" type="submit" value="Zpevnik">
    </form>
    <form class="header_navbar_form" action="/Home/Partners">  
        <input class="header_navbar_form_input" type="submit" value="Partneri">
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#header_navbar_div {
    padding-top: 2px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.header_navbar_form {

    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}

.header_navbar_form_input {
    width: 11%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-color: darkolivegreen;
    background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    color: darkolivegreen;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Try changing all the form elements to divs. (You can only have one form element in web forms, not sure about cshtml.) Also you have `.header_navbar_form` width at 50% and 9 elements with that, so 450% width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I openned the application in Edge instead of Firefox and the CSS took effect, so i cleared a cache of Mozzila and it works. Kind of noobie but, solved the problem. Thanks for efforts.

Jackob